# Change elements order in a matrix (python)

Tags: python, matrix

```
mat = [[0],[1],[2]]
```

I want to "cycle" the element of my matrix like this:

```
mat = [[2],[0],[1]]
mat = [[1],[2],[0]]
mat = [[0],[1],[2]]
...
```

How can I change the index of these elements to loop like above?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's unclear to me when you want to permute the elements and how you are going to access them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> for i in xrange(len(mat)):
...  print(mat[i:] + mat[:i])
... 
[[0], [1], [2]]
[[1], [2], [0]]
[[2], [0], [1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

For large lists using a combination of [deque](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque) and a [generator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) will be most efficient:

```
>>> import collections.deque
>>> def list_cycler_gen(lst):
        q = collections.deque(lst,len(lst))
        while True:
            q.appendleft(q.pop())
            yield list(q)

>>> gen = list_cycler_gen([[0],[1],[2]])
>>> gen.next()
[[2], [0], [1]]
>>> gen.next()
[[1], [2], [0]]
>>> gen.next()
[[0], [1], [2]]
```

This will work with anything you place in the list.
Also, if you would have wanted to cycle in the other direction, you could replace the first loop line with:

```
q.append(q.popleft())
```

Comment: I'd say reverse the order of the `yield` and `append` operations so the first value is the initial one.